# How to properly check if there are two model values in the object array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to check if there are two keys and their values in the structure array, but I get no result, how can this be fixed?

Configuration:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    values: [
      {
        One: "One",
        Two: "Two",
        Three: "Three"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    values: [
      {
        One: "One",
        Two: "Two",
        Four: "Four"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Query

```
Model.find({
  "values": {
    $all: [
      {
        One: "One",
        Three: "Three",
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can use `$elemMatch` to get desired value:

```
db.collection.find({
  "values": {
    $elemMatch: {
      One: "One",
      Three: "Three"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DZuoyo2SH8H).

Also [another example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x00SRmNGG8P) with more values.